# How to pass values from pandas column into scipy.stats.binomtest in a vectorized way and store answers in new column?

Tags: python, scipy, vectorization, scipy.stats

I have the dataframe `births`:

|  | year | sex | num_births | total_births |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1880 | M | 110491 | 201484 |
| 3 | 1881 | M | 100743 | 192696 |
| 5 | 1882 | M | 113686 | 221533 |
| 7 | 1883 | M | 104627 | 216946 |
| 9 | 1884 | M | 114442 | 243462 |
| 11 | 1885 | M | 107799 | 240854 |
| 13 | 1886 | M | 110784 | 255317 |
| 15 | 1887 | M | 101413 | 247394 |
| 17 | 1888 | M | 120851 | 299473 |
| 19 | 1889 | M | 110580 | 288946 |

And I want to test use the binomtest from scipy and add the p-value to a new column:

```
(births
 .assign(binom_pvalue=lambda x: stats.binomtest(x.num_births, x.total_births).pvalue)
)
```

but I get the error `TypeError: k must be an integer.`

It looks like I am passing the whole series instead of the value for each row.
However, this methods works when doing something like:

```
(num_births
 .assign(ratio=lambda x: x.num_births / x.total_births)
)
```

output:

|  | year | sex | num_births | total_births | ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1880 | M | 110491 | 201484 | 0.548386 |
| 3 | 1881 | M | 100743 | 192696 | 0.522808 |
| 5 | 1882 | M | 113686 | 221533 | 0.513179 |
| 7 | 1883 | M | 104627 | 216946 | 0.482272 |
| 9 | 1884 | M | 114442 | 243462 | 0.470061 |

In this scenario, it uses the value for each row in a vectorized fashion.

How can I use the binomtest function, using the same style as I am trying above?

Thankful for answers!

William

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using `lambda` and `assign`:

```py
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import binomtest

births = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "year": [1880, 1881],
        "sex": ["M", "M"],
        "num_births": [110491, 100743],
        "total_births": [201484, 192696],
    }
)

births.assign(
    p_value=lambda pvalue: [
        binomtest(i, j).pvalue for i, j in zip(births.num_births, births.total_births)
    ]
)
```

The following is the output:

```py
   year sex  num_births  total_births       p_value
0  1880   M      110491        201484  0.000000e+00
1  1881   M      100743        192696  3.317445e-89
```

Comment: Sorry, but that approach does not follow the style that I want to use.

Comment: I have updated my answer to strictly follow your style guideline. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, it relies on a for loop, I want a vectorized solution. I will have to continue the search. Thanks anyways.